# Need to generate report using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a table and I want to generate report from it.
[image]

I need to generate reporter using LINQ given the route and shift it returns the list of dates with the number of subscriptions for each day.
i.e

given route 2022, shift 2120 it give me a list with the following

```
 date               count
    2015-05-01          5
    2015-05-02          10
    2015-05-03          8
    ....
```

any clue ?

Comment: Your expected output doesn't match with your input data.

Comment: I have 200K  records of data I am just giving an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input does not match the output. But I am assuming you are showing partial input from your data. Then You can try,

```
var result = mydata.Where(x=>x.route.Equals("2022") && x.shift.Equals("2120"))
            .GroupBy(x=> x.Date).Select(grp => new {Date = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count()});
```

Comment: any way to convert the result to list ? as it crashes if I used .tolist() ?

Comment: this code crashes says Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.